# Printing out contents of an array?

Tags: java, arrays, class, methods

I have an issue with my java program. I created an array of integers using my SelectionSortArray class. The issue I am having is that when I try to print out the contents of my created array it displays some other random lines of codes which is obviously an error. Below is my work so far. If you guys can copy and paste it and run it yourselves and tell what is wrong I will appreciate.  Again it does not print the contents from my array when I run my demo/main.

The end result should print out this:

```
10
20
30
```

My demo/main:

```
  public static void main(String[] args) {

    SelectionSortArray[] ints = new SelectionSortArray[3];

    ints [0] = new SelectionSortArray(10);
    ints [1] = new SelectionSortArray(20);
    ints [2] = new SelectionSortArray(30);

    for (int index = 0; index < ints.length; index++) {
        System.out.println(ints[index]);
    }


  }
```

My class that I'm using to create the array:

```
public class SelectionSortArray implements Comparable<SelectionSortArray> {

public int num;

public SelectionSortArray(int initialNum) {
    num = initialNum;
}

public int compareTo(SelectionSortArray other) {

    int result;

    if (num == other.num) {
        result = 0;
    } else if (num < other.num) {
        result = 1;
    } else {
        result = 2;
    }

    return result;

}
}
```

Comment: You would also be well off to be in the habit of writing your `compareTo` method to use `Integer.compareTo(anotherInteger)` rather than manually typing that all out.  Just store your `num` as an `Integer` rather than an `int`, then change the `compareTo` method to have a single line: `return num.compareTo(other.num);`

Comment: @chrylis no its not a duplicate. and i read what you linked it doesn't help me. I am using a class to create my array in my demo/main.

Comment: @StormeHawke Or just use `Integer` instead of writing a new low-functionality wrapper class.

Comment: @chrylis agreed, though I'm not going to pass judgement on how functional the wrapper class is since I don't know if this is all of the code from the class or just a small example to demonstrate his problem

Comment: @StormeHawke I'm basing mine on the description that `ints` is "an array of integers".

Comment: @chrylis if that is the complete description of what this class does then by all means this class is a waste of code :)

Answer (score 3):

You need to override `toString()` method in `SelectionSortArray` something like this

```
class SelectionSortArray {
   ....


   public String toString() {
      return String.valueOf(num);
   }

}
```

- When you `System.out.println` your object, JVM will print `toString()` representation of the object
- If this method is not overridden, it will display the default `toString()` implementation of `Object`, which is `classname@hexdecimal_code`.

Answer (score 1):

No, you don't have an array of integers, you have an array of `SelectionSortArray`s for no clear reason. To make your existing code work, you need to implement `toString()` on `SelectionSortArray`. To make your existing code *sane*, just replace your `SelectionSortArray` (which isn't an array) with `int` or `Integer`.

Answer (score 0):

Its actually prints `SelectionSortArray`  objects `toString`. which would be class name with @ and hashcode of you `SelectionSortArray` object.

`toString` method in `Object` class for [ref](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/lang/Object.java#Object.toString%28%29).

```
public String toString() {
      return getClass().getName() + "@" + Integer.toHexString(hashCode());
}
```

you should override `toString` method of `Object` class to `SelectionSortArray` like @sanbhat has suggested.

Comment: Some hopefully constructive feedback: this answer, while true, doesn't actually do much to help an obviously new programmer figure out how to fix his problem...

Comment: ummm beside that he/she must understand the root cause, to become better ;)